# Voice broadcasting options

Tags: pbx

I am investigating options for doing recorded telephone message calls to batches of users (about 400 max) for a client.

Ideally a vendor or technology with little or no startup cost, and a reasonable per-use fee - the calls would be used by a emergency management department only to announce updates to town residents in case of emergency, so we could go years without using it, and would rather pay a bit more for each call when we use it then pay monthly for a system that will likely not get that much use.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already out there: http://www.onecallnow.com/

The company happens to be headquartered in the town I live in, and I've met the owner a couple of times. I have no relationship with the company but I've heard that their Customers really like it. The owner and I talked about their back-end technology a couple of months ago and I was impressed that they clearly had "tech people" who knew what they were doing.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are hundreds of them out there, each offering various packages for prices, most have a emergency only option for cities.  I will link a few of them below.

[School messenger](http://www.schoolmessenger.com/)- Have heard good things, mostly focused on schools 
[US Netcom](http://www.usnetcomcorp.com/contact.htm)- have had bad experiences with them
[Connect Ed](http://www.ntigroup.com/products/connect-ed.asp)- seems to offer the best integration for what you are looking for
[Synrevoice](http://www.synrevoice.com/)- focuses mainly on school connections

Usually these services will charge an initial connection fee, followed up by a monthly maintenance fee.  For emergency services only, they will generally have a set limit of the amount of calls you can make per year, with any additional calls being made at an additional expense.  I am more familiar with their school pricing, however, so I can not speak to additional practices.  good luck.